# Multiple splines on the same plot with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add an other spline to the plot below, but if I do it the `geom_point()` will only display the points on the first spline.

```
n <- 10
d <- data.frame(x = 1:n, y = rnorm(n))
ggplot(d,aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_line(data=data.frame(spline(d, n=n*10)))
```

[image]

How can I display the dots on the second line too?

Comment: you could add another geom_line with the new spline, or make all the splines before hand and put into on data.frame

Comment: I added the other line with geom_line, and it works, except that it only display the points, on the first spline. The second spline is "naked".

Comment: Ah - I misunderstood what you were trying to do. Please can you update your example to show what you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you initially have the data you want in two data.frames, this code will work. It makes the spline before using ggplot.

```
n <- 10
d <- data.frame(x = 1:n, y = rnorm(n))
d2 <- data.frame(x = 1:n, y = rnorm(n))
dd <- rbind(cbind(d, case = "d"), cbind(d2, case = "d2"))
ddsmooth <- plyr::ddply(dd, .(case), function(k) as.data.frame(spline(k, n = n * 10)))
ggplot(dd,aes(x, y, group = case)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_line(aes(x, y, group  = case), data = ddsmooth)
```

If your data are in different columns of a data.frame, use reshape2::melt to process it.