# Multiple Splines using ggplot2 + Different colours + Line width + Custom X-axis markings

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, interpolation, spline

I have a two small sets of points, viz. `(1,a1),...,(9,a9)` and `(1,b1),...,(9,b9)`. I'm trying to *interpolate these two set of points separately by using splines* with the help of `ggplot2`. So, what I want is **2 different splines curves interpolating the two sets of points on the same plot** (Refer to the end of this post).

Since I have a very little plotting experience using `ggplot2`, I copied a code snippet from [this answer by Richard Telford](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36813937/12036804). At first, I stored my Y-values for set of points in two numeric variables **A** and **B**, and wrote the following code :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
A <- c(a1,...,a9)
B <- c(b1,...,b9)
d <- data.frame(x=1:9,y=A)
d2 <- data.frame(x=1:9,y=B)
dd <- rbind(cbind(d, case = "d"), cbind(d2, case = "d2"))
ddsmooth <- plyr::ddply(dd, .(case), function(k) as.data.frame(spline(k)))
ggplot(dd,aes(x, y, group = case)) + geom_point() + geom_line(aes(x, y, group  = case), data = ddsmooth)
```

This produces the following output :

[image: spline_rplot]

***Now, I'm seeking for an almost identical plot with the following customizations :***

- The two spline curves should have different colours
- The line width should be user's choice (Like we do in `plot` function)
- A legend (Specifying the colour and the corresponding attribute)
- Markings on the X-axis should be 1,2,3,...,9

Hoping for a detailed solution to my problem, though any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already shaped your data correctly for the plot. It's just a case of associating the `case` variable with colour and size scales.

Note the following:

1. I have inferred the values of `A` and `B` from your plot
2. Since the lines are opaque, we plot them first so that the points are still visible
3. I have included `size` and `colour` parameters to the `aes` call in `geom_line`
4. I have selected the colours by passing them as a character vector to `scale_colour_manual`
5. I have also selected the sizes of the lines by calling `scale_size_manual`
6. I have set the x axis breaks by adding a call to `scale_x_continuous`
7. The legend has been added automatically according to the scales used.

```r
ggplot(dd, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = case, size = case, linetype = case), data = ddsmooth) +
  geom_point(colour = "black") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red4", "forestgreen"), name = "Legend") +  
  scale_size_manual(values = c(0.8, 1.5), name = "Legend") +  
  scale_linetype_manual(values = 1:2, name = "Legend") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:9)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It's precisely what I wanted. Anyway, can you please tell me what can I do for more customizations like substituting the word "case" by "legend" in the above diagram, make one of the lines dashed etc. ? These aren't much needed, I'm asking out of curiosity.

In general, can you please tell me some good resources for mastering R plots using packages like `ggplot2`, `lattice` etc. ?

Comment: Hi @JRC glad I could help. There are very many customizations you can do, and [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/) is a good link to get you started. Comments probably aren't the best place for me to explain all the customizations, but for line type you can use `linetype = case` in your `aes` call, and add a `scale_linetype_manual(values = 1:2)` to the plot. If you want to change the name of a particular scale as displayed in the legend, add `name = "Legend"` to the `scale_(whatever)_manual` call.

Comment: For the legend thingy, can you please give an example ? I guess I'm misunderstanding your statement, because if I add `name="Legend"` inside `scale_colour_manual`, 2 separate legends are produced ; one with the title "case", other one with the title "Legend". I'm seeking for one legend with the title "Legend" (By the way, I could change the names of the lines).

Comment: @JRC no, that's right. If you want the different scales to be merged, give them all the same name. This allows you to have separate named scales for line type, colour, size etc if you wish

Comment: I'm so sorry for bothering you, but can you please tell me exactly what to write in order to make the legend title "Legend" ??

Comment: @JRC thought it probably easiest to just update. I have added a linetype scale, and have given all the aesthetic scales the `name = "Legend"` to produce this plot. I hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: Can't thank you enough. This is absolutely perfect. Upvoted your answer. Thank you. :)